Keys are not fully imported while cloning db on redis cloud to local environment
I have a database on Redis cloud and I am gonna clone this db into my local environment.
So I have installed the same Redis version 6.2.1 on my local Ubuntu. I have also enabled all the required submodules, such as timeseries, JSON, and others.
I have downloaded the backup files from an S3 bucket and tried to import them using the rdbtools utility.
However, as I mentioned earlier, the keys are not being imported fully. I have reviewed the documentation, but I'm still facing challenges with the import process.
I found that timeseries and json data are missing while other primary key types were imported correctly. Dump data is splitted into 16 gzip files and each file size is bigger than 3 GB.

you're having trouble importing your Redis database. The issue you're facing might be due to the size of your dump files. When a database is large, it's possible to encounter issues during import.
For Redis 6.0 and later, you can use the redis-cli command with the --rdb option to import the database. Here's an example:
redis-cli --rdb /path/to/rdb/file/db.rdb
However, due to the size of your dump files, you might need to increase the timeout and slave-read-only-timeout settings in your Redis configuration file. This will ensure that your Redis instance has enough time to process the large amount of data.
If the issue persists, you might want to consider importing the data in smaller batches to avoid any potential issues.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
